# add damage to an object

Tags: materials, texturing

I have a metal arm object I built, it is using a stainless steel material in cycles. I am looking for a way to "age" it by adding nicks, cuts, damage, and possibly rust on the edges?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3337/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3370/599. You could try adding some grunge/scratch textures too.

Comment: Hi and welcome to BSE. You are asking for a tutorial on the subject "add damage to an object". We would like to help you but tutorials are off topic here. First, we would like to know what you have tried so far. Post some images. Narrow down the question. For instance: "how to change material based on mesh topology" (placing rust on the edges).