# How can I animate the visibility of a face?

Tags: animation

I am making an animation where the character is shimming across a ledge, and the ledge starts to crumble.  I would have to delete faces of the ledge to make them crumble.  How can I do that?

Comment: Try looking at the answers on this question and see if they help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/procedurally-generating-wear-on-an-object If not, leave a comment asking for more help.

Comment: You can also try this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3370/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-image-based-on-edges-and-corners but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a *Mask modifier* if you really want to delete certain faces on a certain frame, however I'm not sure this is really what you want to do.

## Mask modifier:

If you really want to delete a specific face (or faces) on a certain frame, then you can use the [*Mask modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html#mask-modifier).

1. Select the faces you want to hide and assign them to a vertex group in *Properties > Object data > Vertex groups*
2. Add a mask modifier and select your vertex group and enable *Invert* by clicking the button next to the vertex group selector:

   [image]
3. Keyframe the visibility of the modifier by hovering over the eye icon and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>.

If you want more variation, try using a reversed *Build modifier*. This will delete all faces in the object over time, either randomly or in order.

## Fracturing:

If you are trying to make a more complex/realistic
You might also want to try the Cell fracture addon ([see this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6686/599)):

[image: Example gif]

Or the [explode modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/modeling/modifiers/physics/explode.html#explode-modifier).

Comment: All faces touching a vertex assigned to the Vertex Group also disappear.  To get just a single face to disappear, select that face in Edit Mode, then go to `Mesh` > `Faces` > `Poke Faces`, and only assign the new vertex at the center of the poked face to the Vertex Group.